Homotopy in the space of linear isometries
I wanted to understand the linear isometries operad $\mathscr{L}$ as a model for $E_{\infty}$-operads for which I wanted to show that $\mathscr{L}(n) \simeq *$. This all reduces down to some potentially basic linear algebra that I'm confused about. I'm following the proof of Lewis-May-Steinberger, Lemma II.1.5.
Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty} = \operatorname{colim}_n \mathbb{R}^n$ which on underlying sets is given by the direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{R}$. We write $\mathbb{R}^{\infty} = \mathbb{R}_1 \oplus \mathbb{R}_2 \oplus \cdots$. Consider the map $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^{\infty} \to \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ which sends $\mathbb{R}_i$ identically onto $\mathbb{R}_{2i}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. We write $\mathscr{L}(-,-)$ for linear isometric embeddings between inner product spaces. It obtains the compact-open topology.
Question. How do we obtain a homotopy $H : [0,1] \to \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}, \mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ from $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}}$ to $\alpha$?
Lewis-May-Steinberger suggest to take a linear path and then to normalize. I'd interpret this as taking $t \mapsto t \alpha + (1-t) \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}}$ and applying some normalization procedure on this. What's the normalization that makes this into a linear isometry?

What norm / metric are you using on $\Bbb R^\infty$?

@FShrike Good point, I forgot to define it. (I guess because the papers I'm reading all also tacitly assume it.) Any two elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ lie inside some $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then take the usual Euclidean inner product/norm/metric.

Let's take $u \in \Bbb{R}^\infty$ and compute (with respecto to the usual metric / Euclidian inner product / norm) :
$$
\begin{align}
\|(t\alpha + (1-t)\operatorname{id}_{\Bbb{R}^\infty})(u)\|^2 
   &= \langle (t\alpha + (1-t)\operatorname{id}_{\Bbb{R}^\infty})(u), (t\alpha + (1-t)\operatorname{id}_{\Bbb{R}^\infty})(u) \rangle \\
   &= t^2\langle\alpha(u),\alpha(u)\rangle + 2t(1-t)\langle u,\alpha(u)\rangle + (1-t)^2\langle u,u\rangle & (a) \\
   &= t^2\langle\alpha(u),\alpha(u)\rangle + 2t(1-t)\langle\alpha(u),\alpha(u)\rangle + (1-t)^2\langle u,u\rangle & (b) \\
   &= (2t-t^2)\|\alpha(u)\|^2 + (1-t)^2\|u\|^2 \\
   &= \|u\|^2 & (c)
\end{align}
$$
where we use $(a)$  the bilinearity and symmetry of the inner product, $(b)$ the fact that $\langle u,\alpha(u) \rangle = \langle \alpha(u),\alpha(u) \rangle$ by the definition of $\alpha$, $(c)$ by isometry of $\alpha$. It allows us to conclude that $H(t) = t\alpha + (1-t)\operatorname{id}_{\Bbb{R}^\infty} \in \mathscr{L}(\Bbb{R}^\infty,\Bbb{R}^\infty)$.

Ohhhh, I totally missed $\langle u, \alpha(u) \rangle = \langle \alpha(u), \alpha(u) \rangle$. Perfekt, thank you!

You're welcome ;)

User Junyeong Park has a question concerning your answer. He does not yet have enough reputation to write a comment. See his question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4953554/349785.
