Contractibility of the space of linear isometries
I am trying to understand the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4895380/1367197.
However, I cannot figure out why (b) works.
For example, if $e_i$ is the $i$-th orthonormal basis, then $\langle e_i,\alpha(e_i)\rangle=\langle e_i,e_{2i}\rangle=0$ however $\langle\alpha(e_i),\alpha(e_i)\rangle=\langle e_{2i},e_{2i}\rangle=1$.
By the way, how can I find the desired homotopy between the identity map and $\alpha$?

You should also write a comment to the linked answer asking for clarification.

I tried to, but this site requires "50 reputation" to write a comment. Since I am new to this site, I do not know how to get "reputation"...

Then I shall write a comment drawing attention to your question.

Reputation is gained via questions and answers. Other users can upvote your contributions which gives 10 reputation per upvote. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation. Also read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Your first question is a really good one because you precisely explained your doubts.

I have resolved my question. The "normalization" process in the text means the Gram-Schmidt process. More precisely, one begins with the usual linear homotopy and then gets a parametrized basis in the target space (e.g. the image of an orthonormal basis for the source space). Then use the Gram-Schmidt to get a parametrized orthonormal basis for the target space. Since the resulting basis is still a continuous family with respect to the given parameter, one gets the desired homotopy.
